# Networking - Two Raspberry Pis communicating over wired connection

Tags: networking, hardware, ethernet, communication

As a part of my research I need to have two Raspberry Pis and a [Pixhawk](https://pixhawk.org/) all within the body of a UAV. I know I can get one Pi connected to the Pixhawk over [mavlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAVLink), but how can I get the two Pis talking to each other. The three devices will all be effectively adjacent to each other, and due to the large interference (ESCs etc) within the drone i'd rather stick to wired.

Additionally, weight and power is a concern so i would rather avoid using any extra components if possible.

Comment: Most Pis have an Ethernet socket.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It isn't clear from your question what you'd like to communicate between the Pis - the requirements for sending LED on/off signals are very different to those for sending full rate high definition video, for example. Please edit your question to include as much detail as you can - what are you sending, at what kind of rates, with what kind of failure requirements?

Comment: In the Pixhawk description, I don't see any Ethernet interfaces, but there are multiple UART interfaces.  If you have one or two unused UART ports on the Pixhawk, you can connect the serial port on one or both Pi to the Pixhawk, just remember to cross send and recieve lines, tx <-> rx, rx <-> tx.  On the Pi, something has to open the UART, set speed, etc. and initiate communication with the Pixhawk.  You can connect the two Pi with Ethernet (either patch or cross-over cable).  Use static IP addresses and a cable type that matches or exceeds the speed you want to run.

Comment: Of course what you really need is software running in all three units.  Whatever communication protocols and commands required by that software are what you need.